# How to determine solutions to homogenous systems Ax = 0?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a 4x4 matrix which I need to determine the solutions for Ax = 0 as well as one basis of the space of solutions.

What I've done so far was to reduce the matrix to the echelon form and I ended up with:

[image]
Then I wrote:

(x = -2y)
(y = z)
(w = 0)

How do I find the solutions now? And how do I find a basis among the solutions?

Comment: are those vectors the colums of the matrix or the rows?

Comment: your matrix is still not in echelon form, the last two rows are same.

Comment: oh, what shall I do to get them in echelon form?

Comment: Substract $R_3$ from $R_4$ and also you have to work on $R_2$ as well . Also note that the first variable, call it $x$, is a free variable. The first row will give you $2y+w=0$ and so on.

Comment: @AnuragA the matrix picture was actually wrong. I've just edited it. The element a11 is a 1 not zero and before

Comment: You have changed the matrix again. So now things are different. $x$ is no longer free variable. Once you do echelon form, you will see that $z$ is the free variable. The first row will give you $x+2y+w=0$ and so on. But you still have to work on $R_4$.

Comment: I have:

x + 2y + w =0
y - z + 3/5w = 0
6/5w = 0

Comment: @MiltonLeal that's correct. So now you get $w=0$ and work your way backwards.

Comment: Doing that, I think I will find:
(x = -2y) (y = z) (w = 0)

Comment: But I don't see the solutions. How do I formally write the solutions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110826/discussion-between-milton-leal-and-anurag-a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make the 4'd row as zero rows by subtracing $R_3$ and $R_4$

from there we getting the matrix : $$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&0&1\\ 0&1&-1&\frac{3}{5}\\ 0&0&0&\frac{6}{5}\\ 0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ from here we can see we have $z$ as free variable so we can write the following:
$$w=0$$ $$y=z$$ $$x=-2z$$

so we can write a general vector in the null space : $(x,y,z,w) = (-2z,z,z,0)= z(-2,1,1,0)$ while $z\in \mathbb{F}$ depends on the field u working on.
wich we can conclude that the null space is spanned by the vector $(-2,1,1,0)$

Comment: The null space spanned by the vector (-2,1,1,0) can be considered a basis?

Comment: Yes, because the dimension of the null space is $1$